# Set Value of a CheckBoxPreference in an Activity

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, checkboxpreference

Hello I need to know how to set a value programmatically.

I am using that code

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                            .
                            .
                            .

SharedPreferences.Editor geted = prefs.edit();
geted.putBoolean("checkBox_Schedule", false);
geted.commit();
```

But I dont see anything change

The code of my xml for my checkboxPreference is

```
 <CheckBoxPreference

 android:defaultValue="false"
 android:dependency="checkBox"
 android:key="checkBox_Schedule"
 android:summary="On/Off"
 android:title="Schedule" />
```

One solution is to do

```
 startActivity(new Intent(SetPreference.this, SetPreference.class));
```

But this is not what I want to do.

Comment: it has a defaultValue of false. and you are again changing it to false. How do you expect to see a change?

Comment: I use the code of my commit inside an if where the user has previously changed the value to true

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
CheckBoxPreference showContact = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("myPreference");
showContact.setChecked(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call this in your preference activity

```
    CheckBoxPreference pref = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("example_pref_key");
    pref.setChecked(false);
```